# C++ invalid conversion from char to const char*

Tags: c++, char, constants

How do I fix this function? Error I'm getting is: invalid conversion from char to const char* on line

```
if(strcmp('\0', p->pubLow[i][j]) == 0) {
```

Code:

```
struct Prefix {
    int  no;             // number of entries
    int  area[MAX];      // area elements
    char pubLow[MAX][8]; // low end of publisher range
    char pubHgh[MAX][8]; // high end of publisher range
    int  pubLen[MAX];    // no of chars in publisher string
};

int minNoDigits(const Prefix* p, int area) {
    int minNoDigits = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < p->no; i++) {
        if(area == p->area[i]) {
            cout << "p->pubLow[i] is: " << p->pubLow[i] << endl;
            minNoDigits = 1;
            for(int j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
                if(p->pubLow[i][j] = '\0') {
                    j = 3;
                    i = p->no;
                }
                else {
                    minNoDigits++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return minNoDigits;
}
```

**Edit** to provide more information.

I've changed the line to

```
if(p->pubLow[i][j] = '\0') {
```

New error:

```
assignment of read-only location p->Prefix::pubLow[i][j]
```

Comment: What is the type of `pubLow`?

Comment: @KirilKirov pubLow seems to be char**

Comment: @OP ***Why*** can't you just ***read the documentation*** of `strcmp()`? Seriously...

Comment: You have taken the code from the answer incorrectly, which is why you're getting an error about assignment. Read it carefully, see what's different, and understand it.

Comment: @OP this would indeed be answered by the documentation of `strcmp`, as **H2CO3** already mentioned (-1)

Answer (score 5):

I understand `p->pubLow[i][j]` is actually a `char`, because `pubLow` seems from your code to be a `char**` so this is what you are looking for:

```
if(p->pubLow[i][j] == '\0') {
```

`strcmp()` has the following prototype:

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Here is the [**documentation**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

So, to summarize, you are trying to compare **2 charaters** and `strcmp()` is designed to compare **2 constant strings**.

Comment: Note: "\0" are two zero characters.

Comment: I think they are trying to compare the termination character with each character of `pubLow[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` compares strings from `const char*`s:

```
if(strcmp("", p->pubLow[i][j]) == 0) {
```

Comment: Note: "\0" are two zero characters.

Comment: @nestedloop, well, using `strcmp` is not such an overhead as it seemed :) thank you for your attention.

Comment: @IvanGrynko Upon looking at the OP's code, it seems p->pubLow[i][j] is actually a char.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need strcmp(...) for char comparsion?
You can do just

```
if('\0'== p->pubLow[i][j]) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`'\0'` is a char not a string like other have replied.

I'm not sure what you want tot achieve with `if(strcmp('\0', p->pubLow[i][j]) == 0)`

If you want to check end of string you can do this `if('\0' == p->pubLow[i][j])`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `p->pubLow[i]` is a `char*` and you're trying to compare it character-by-character with the termination character `\0`?

As others have pointed out, `strcmp` is meant to be used to compare strings not individual characters. You could use `==` operator to compare the characters instead, but since you're doing this to find the length of the string, it would be better to do this directly.

You want to return the number of digits in the `p->pubLow[i]` with the same area as `area`, right? How about this:

```
int minNoDigits(const Prefix* p, int area) {
    for(int i = 0; i < p->no; i++) {
        if(area == p->area[i]) {
            cout << "p->pubLow[i] is: " << p->pubLow[i] << endl;
            return strlen(pubLow[i]) + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You might also find `break` useful in future - it will break you out of the `for` loops (I notice you were setting `j` and `i` directly to do this).